# How to get all custom attribute data using product id with custom query?

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9

I have no idea about how to get all products custom attributes data using product id but not using like this :
`$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(674);`

I need using custom MySql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addIdFilter(674)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Using `echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();` will print a SQL query like:

> SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, [...] FROM `catalog_product_flat_2` AS `e` WHERE (e.status = 1) AND (e.entity_id = '674')

If you want to outpu all data you can use

```
var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```